# Laravel - How to remove only element from array (Only Left/ Single)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel. I am getting such type of response.

```
{   "id" : "125",
    "name": "xyz",
    "balanced": "2334",
    "mutual-friend": [
        "Carl"
    ]
}
```

I had used foreach loop for adding mutual-friend object which is present in another table and in response it give above output.

I want to remove that single element from array.
What should I use?

Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade implode() of laravel.
Thus I got the required output.

```
{   "id" : "125",
"name": "xyz",
"balanced": "2334",
"mutual-friend":"Carl"
}
```